# Ограничить доступ к методам

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron

Имеется контроллер:

```
class MailsController < ApplicationController
    def every_day
        User.where(subscription: "every_day").find_each do |user|
            UserMailer.with(user: user).send_every_day(hash).deliver_now
        end
    end

    def every_week(hash)
        User.where(subscription: "every_week").find_each do |user|
            UserMailer.with(user: user).send_every_week.deliver_now
        end
    end
end
```

Роут для него:

```
 namespace :mails do
    get "every_day"
    get "every_week"
  end
```

Как мне сделать эти 2 метода недоступными из браузера:

```
http://localhost:3000/mails/every_day
```

При этом эти методы использует cron, выполняя их с определённой периодичностью.

Comment: для cron, думаю нужно использовать задачи, не методы контроллера напрямую

Answer (score 0):

Доброго времени суток.

Если Ваш cron запускается на машине с этим приложением, то я бы порекомендовал перенести функционал из контроллера в rake-задачи. А в случае, если хотите "дергать" методы из-вне, то потребуется авторизация, например [jwt](https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt).